# Write proper Ansi C makefile for Windows

Tags: c, windows, makefile, compilation

I'm really desperate when trying to write a C makefile for windows for my school project. I already have my makefile written and used for ubuntu and it works perfectly like this:

```
all: clean install

install: dynarr.o broadcaster.o main.o
    gcc -o freq dynarr.o broadcaster.o main.o

clean:
    rm -f *.o

dynarr.o:
    gcc -c dynarr.c

broadcaster.o:
    gcc -c broadcaster.c

main.o:
    gcc -c main.c
```

I've already tried just about 10 tutorials on various sites and it is getting on my nerve.
I need to compile *dynarr.c broadcaster.c main.c* in this particular order and the output should be *freq.exe*. Compiler on the school server is gcc for both versions(linux and windows).
Please help me.

Edit: For some reason our teacher's online validator required freq.exe for both windows and linux and he did not bother to mention it anywhere. Everything I had to edit was `freq` to `freq.exe`. Thanks for support.

Comment: We can't guess what exactly is wrong. Edit your question to reflect that, with the error message and/or what is and what should be.

Comment: well, the problem is that the server won't give me any better clue than *the file freq.exe could not be created, test cannot continue* any validation only would also help but I couldn't find anything usefull

Comment: What exact command are you running?

Comment: I can't really tell, I don't see inside the tests. I already reached out to my teacher, waiting for his response.
Meanwhile I constructed this:
`CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -pedantic -ansi
LIBS = -lm 
BIN = freq.exe
OBJ = dynarr.o broadcaster.o main.o

$(BIN): $(OBJ)
 $(CC) $^ -o $@ -lm

%.o: %.c
 $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< $(LIBS) -o $@ `
and it seems it should be allright, but isn't. Could you please check it for some errors?

Comment: Note that `make` and C are separate and independent, except inasmuch as `make` implementations may be written in C.  Thus, the phrase "Ansi C makefile" doesn't have a well-defined meaning.  I guess you just want a makefile for building your particular C program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, you expect the compiler to produce a file named `freq.exe` (or the test system does, anyway) but the command you issue tells GCC to emit a file named just `freq`, instead.  The latter seems natural for Linux, so it is not surprising that your build works as expected there.

It is tricky to support different OS families with the same makefile, which is why utilities such as the Autotools and CMake were invented.  Supposing that you only need a Makefile for Windows, this variation should suffice:

```
all: clean install

install: dynarr.o broadcaster.o main.o
    gcc -o freq.exe dynarr.o broadcaster.o main.o

clean:
    rm -f *.o

dynarr.o:
    gcc -c dynarr.c

broadcaster.o:
    gcc -c broadcaster.c

main.o:
    gcc -c main.c
```

---

With that said, I have some suggestions for further improvement:

1. A rule for building a specific output file should name that file as its target.
2. Conversely, targets of rules that do not correspond to a file created by that rule should be declared "phony" by naming them as prerequisites of a target named `.PHONY`.
3. By convention, an "install" target copies built files from their build location to a permanent system location.  Neither your install rule nor anything else in your makefile does that, so you probably don't need an "install" target.
4. It is perhaps intentional that your rule for the default target cleans before it builds, but that is abnormal, as it defeats one of the major reasons for using `make` in the first place: to avoid needless work.
5. It is good form and it protects against errors to use Make's automatic variables to avoid repeating yourself in rules.
6. There is some divergence of opinion, but I think the general consensus is that a `clean` target should clean up all built objects, not just intermediate ones.

Applying all those would yield a makefile such as this:

```
all: freq.exe

freq.exe: dynarr.o broadcaster.o main.o
    gcc -o $@ $^

clean:
    rm -f freq.exe *.o

dynarr.o:
    gcc -c dynarr.c

broadcaster.o:
    gcc -c broadcaster.c

main.o:
    gcc -c main.c

.PHONY: all clean
```

---

Personally, I would also suggest introducing variables for the executable target (which would make it easier to adapt the makefile between Windows and Linux / macOS) and for the required object files (which is typical, and which would allow the `clean` target to be more precise).  You could also consider relying on Make's built-in rules for building .o files from .c files, as the explicit rules you're using don't do anything that the is not also done by the built-in one.  The result might be:

```
PROG = freq.exe
OBJS = dynarr.o broadcaster.o main.o

all: $(PROG)

$(PROG): $(OBJS)
    gcc -o $@ $^

clean:
    rm -f $(PROG) $(OBJS)

# Relies on the built-in rules for building object files from C sources

.PHONY: all clean
```

Comment: There is one thing to do to keep your sanity with makefiles, please replace the tab by > , to do that on top of your file you type : .RECIPEPREFIX= >

Comment: In the end it turned out that our professor wanted the linux makefile to generate file named freq.exe for some reason. In combination with no proper error log it really confused great amount of my classmates and me. Thanks, solved.